# ¿Como puedo cambiar la visibilidad de un objeto xml en ViewModel?

Tags: android, android-studio, xml, kotlin

tengo una duda de como cambiara la visibilidad de un objeto en el ViewModel.

Os expongo mi caso: Tengo una interfaz de login que tiene dos Edittext Y dos botones, un botón y un Edittext están en invisible por defecto, y quiero que al pulsar el botón que esta visible haga invisible el primer Edittext y el botón que he pulsado y haga visible el segundo botón y el segundo Edittext. Y aquí llega el problema, todo esto sabría hacerlo en la Activity, pero necesito hacerlo en ViewModel y no tengo ni idea de como acceder a los componentes xml desde ahí.

Se que todo esto es lioso asi que paso a enviar las clases y si alguien me pudiese decir como hacer esto se lo agradeceria. Gracias.

XML del Login:

```
<data>
    <variable
        name="viewModel"
        type="com.quobis.sippo.ecco.viewmodel.LoginViewModel"/>
</data>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="LoginUser">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="250dp"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:src="@drawable/logom"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.2"
    />


    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/usr"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:hint="@string/hint_user"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:textColorPrimary="@color/colorLetterLogin"
        android:backgroundTint="@color/colorBackButtLogin"
        android:elevation="20dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginLeft="60dp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.6"
        app:addTextChangedListener="@{viewModel.emailTextWatcher}"
    />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_usr"
        android:layout_width="55dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:background="@color/colorBackButtLogin"
        android:drawableBottom="@drawable/ic_keyboard_arrow_right"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginLeft="260dp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.6"
        android:onClick="@{viewModel::onUserClicked}"
    />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/pass"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:hint="@string/hint_pass"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:shape="rectangle"
        android:inputType="textPassword"
        android:textColorPrimary="@color/colorLetterLogin"
        android:backgroundTint="@color/colorBackButtLogin"
        android:elevation="20dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginLeft="60dp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.6"
        android:visibility="invisible"
        android:onClick="@{viewModel::onLoginClicked}"
        />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_pass"
        android:layout_width="55dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:background="@color/colorBackButtLogin"
        android:drawableBottom="@drawable/ic_keyboard_arrow_right"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginLeft="260dp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.6"
        android:visibility="invisible"
        />

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spinner_usr"
        android:layout_width="120dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginLeft="40dp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.85"
    />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

ViewModel:

```
private val user: UserModel
var userp ="jorge "


init {
    this.user= UserModel(email = "")
}


fun emailTextWatcher(): TextWatcher {
    return object : TextWatcher {
        override fun beforeTextChanged(s: CharSequence?, start: Int, count: Int, after: Int) {
            user.setEmail(s.toString())
        }

        override fun onTextChanged(s: CharSequence?, start: Int, before: Int, count: Int) {

        }


        override fun afterTextChanged(s: Editable) {

        }
    }

}

fun onUserClicked(v: View) {


}

fun onLoginClicked(v:View) {
    if (user.getEmail() == userp)
        listener.onSucces("Correcto")
    else
        listener.onError("Fallo")
}
```

Nota: el método para cambiar la visibilidad seria el onUserClicked.

Activity principal:

```
lateinit var binding: ActivityLoginUserBinding

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    binding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.activity_login_user)
    binding.viewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this, LoginViewModelFactory(this)).get(LoginViewModel::class.java)


    var languages = arrayOf("English", "Español", "Galego")
    val spinner = binding.spinnerUsr
    if (spinner != null) {
        val arrayAdapter = ArrayAdapter(this, R.layout.spinner_item, languages)
        spinner.adapter = arrayAdapter
    }

}


override fun onSucces(message: String) {
    Toast.makeText(this,"Login bueno", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
}

@SuppressLint("ResourceAsColor")
override fun onError(message: String) {
    binding.btnUsr
    btn_usr.setBackgroundColor(R.color.colorFailLogin)
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hola puedes agregar un observableBoolean en el viewmodel parecido a esto

```
private final ObservableBoolean showView = new ObservableBoolean(true);
```

luego en el xml puedes poner esto

```
<layout>
    <data>
        <import type="android.view.View"/>
        <variable name="viewModel" type="com.example.viemodel.MyViewModel"/>
    </data>
    <FrameLayout ...>
       <View android:visiblity="@{viewModel.showView ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE}" .../>
    </FrameLayout>
</layout>
```

luego puedes aplicar cualquier tipo delogica cambiado el valor de showView.

saludos